# Bounded strictly totally ordered semigroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory, semigroups

Is it possible that a strictly totally ordered ($<$) infinite algebraic structure has both maximum and minimum?

There is an example of a strictly totally ordered infinite magma bounded from two sides:
the interval of real numbers $[0,1]$ with operation $x \cdot y = (x + y)/2$.
The operation is compatible with the natural order of the segment.
However, the operation is not associative.

I am looking for an example of a strictly totally ordered infinite semigroup bounded from two sides.
I assume the operation on the semigroup is compatible with the order:
$a < b \implies a \cdot c < b \cdot c$ and $a < b \implies c \cdot a < c \cdot b$ for any elements $a$, $b$, $c$ of the semigroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I claim that a strictly totally ordered semigroup with minimum and maximum element can't have more than one element.

Call the minimum element $0$ and the maximum element $1$. From the strict total ordering it follows that
$$y\cdot1=0\cdot x\implies x=1,\ y=0.$$
This is because
$$x\lt1\implies0\cdot1\le y\cdot1=0\cdot x\lt0\cdot1$$
and
$$0\lt y\implies0\cdot1\lt y\cdot1=0\cdot x\le0\cdot1.$$

Now by associativity we have
$$(0\cdot0)\cdot1=0\cdot(0\cdot1)\implies0\cdot1=1$$
and
$$(0\cdot1)\cdot1=0\cdot(1\cdot1)\implies0\cdot1=0,$$
so
$$1=0\cdot1=0.$$

Comment: Thank you. This is an interesting fact, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**. This was an answer to the original question, without the added condition on the order. I let it as it is to clarify the discussion below.

$({\Bbb N} \cup \{+\infty\}, +)$ is an example of a strictly totally ordered and bounded infinite semigroup. But it is not idempotent, contrary to your claim.

Comment: To me, a *strictly totally ordered semigroup* is an ordered semigroup equipped with a strict total order. An ordered semigroup is a semigroup equipped with a partial order $\leqslant$ compatible with the product: $a \leqslant b$ implies $ac \leqslant bc$ and $ca \leqslant cb$.

Comment: I assume the operation is compatible with the order. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @alex-c But what do you mean by compatible? bof and I proposed two different versions. In any case, please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Corrected. Thank you.